# QGIS 3.12 - added CSV file - only showed 5 points on map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

Already saw the same question 2016 but no answer.
I have loaded my file in QGIS - the layer showed the file and attribute table showed a complete dataset but only 5 points are shown in the map. i made sure that there are no overlapping points.
I'm using Windows 10.
My process:
-saved file as .csv ---> opened QGIS 3.12 --->add layer ---> add delimited text layer ---> file name and layer name automatically filled in ---> encoding is UTF-8 ---> file format: custom delimiters (used tab and comma) ---> record and field options (did not do anything) ---> geometry definition (used point coordinates, filled in x and y fields and used WGS84) --->clicked add

Comment: Have you made sure all your rows have coordinates? Have you made sure you used the correct CRS? Can you provide a data example?

Comment: Please check if the custom delimiters are consistent for all the csv and if the X and Y coordinate are picked correctly in the csv layer.

Comment: could all your points be in the same place.

Comment: Open the attribute table and right click on a row, you can choose options like flash feature and zoom to feature. That can help you find overlayed points or points in the wrong place.

Comment: Hello @Erik! not all rows have coordinates. i also made another csv file where all data with no coordinates are removed from the set. but upon loading it to qgis. the data showed on the map are the same points.

Comment: I now realized my mistake. I extracted the coordinates from google earth and instead of getting the data under coordinates (which is placed in the last column when you open a .kml file thru excel), I used the data under latitude and longtitude. When i checked the data, numbers under the lat and lon are mostly the same. Anyway, sorry for all the fuss. thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I now realized my mistake. I extracted the coordinates from google earth and instead of getting the data under coordinates (which is placed in the last column when you open a .kml file thru excel), I used the data under latitude and longtitude. When i checked the data, numbers under the lat and lon are mostly the same. Anyway, sorry for all the fuss. thank you for all the help